# Adding Category Argument into an Array for WordPress Query

Tags: query-posts, query, array

I'm new to customizing WordPress and am looking to query an array of posts within a certain category. I have a display that's showing an array of all posts from the site:

```
$arguments = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'paged' => $paged,
                'showposts' => $postcount
            );
```

Basically, I want to be able to show an array of all posts that are only in the category "Nutrition". I figured it's a 'category' argument that would be added into this array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [Category Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) to your query array.

```
$arguments = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'showposts' => $postcount,
    'category_name'=> 'your-category-slug'
);
```